# Installing the ARM DS-5 community edition under Ubuntu 64 bit

Tags: eclipse, plugins, arm, ds-5

http://ds.arm.com/ds-5-community-edition/

I have a 64 bit installation of Ubuntu 12.04 Precise Pangolin, i want to install the community edition of DS-5, but i can't.

I have the 32 bit version of Eclipse and the 32 bit version of an official JDK from Oracle.

When i use this URL

```
http://tools.arm.com/eclipse
```

in the Eclipse package manager i see 1 package but when in choose to install it i get this error:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Eclipse plug-ins for DS-5 Community Edition 5.10.0.20120515_072757 (com.arm.ds.community.feature.feature.group 5.10.0.20120515_072757)
  Missing requirement: Eclipse plug-ins for DS-5 Community Edition 5.10.0.20120515_072757 (com.arm.ds.community.feature.feature.group 5.10.0.20120515_072757) requires 'org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.7.0,3.8.0)' but it could not be found
```

my best guess is that my copy of Eclipse ( Juno ) is too recent for this plugin.

Comment: I think ARM explicitly do NOT support 64-bit Ubuntu.

Comment: @PeteFordham some people got this up and running on a 64 bit linux OS, also this kind of error is weird, nothing matches and i can't link this error to a specific package or requirement of any kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ARM DS-5 seems not to work on Eclipse Juno at the moment. But it runs well on Eclipse Indigo and Oracle JDK 6 (32 bit in each case).